# Tooltip need to be added after the the last div in a container which has max-width

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5OvJ.png)

Above is how my code looks now.

```
<div class="main">
<div class= "filters">Category</div>
<div class= "filters">Brand</div>
<div class= "filters">Material</div>
<div class= "filters">Price</div>
<div class= "filters">Size</div>
<div class= "filters">Pattern</div>
<div class= "filters">Average ratings</div>
<div class= "filters">Features</div>
<div class= "filters">Country of Origin</div>
<div class= "filters">Color</div>
<div class= "filters">Discount</div>
</div>
        


.main {
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.filters {
    border: 1px solid #3c4c6b;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I want to add ellipsis kind of view for my main div, so that after the div will reach the end of the container, it will show 3 dots(...) and on hover of 3 dots it will show all the divs in the container. Div will have dynamic data, so normal ellipses giving is sometimes breaking the div into half which is not expected.

[Expected view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5OvJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
.filters:last-child:after {
  content: '...';
}
```

Should do the trick

```css
.main {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.filters {
  border: 1px solid #3c4c6b;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.filters:last-child:after {
  content: '...';
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="filters">Category</div>
  <div class="filters">Brand</div>
  <div class="filters">Material</div>
  <div class="filters">Price</div>
  <div class="filters">Size</div>
  <div class="filters">Pattern</div>
  <div class="filters">Average ratings</div>
  <div class="filters">Features</div>
  <div class="filters">Country of Origin</div>
  <div class="filters">Color</div>
  <div class="filters">Discount</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I need the one line of div should display. Rest divs will display on tooltip. Thanks Charles.

Comment: So you want your '...' to not be in an elipse right after the last one ?